# Shared Memory in C (sysV)

Tags: c, unix, ipc, sysv-ipc

```
struct shared_memory_t {
    int value1; 
    int value2;
    char* buffer; 
};

shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(shared_memory_t) + segsize, 0666|IPC_CREAT);
shared_memory_t* mem = (shared_memory_t*) shmat(*shmid, NULL, 0);
```

So I was trying to map the shared memory to a custom structure. Now I do not know how large the segsize is until user starts program and inputs a value. I wanted buffer to be pointer to beginning of the memory space after the int values. Now if I do this I get memory faults. I can attach it and get the starting memory space with:

```
void* mem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
```

Any hints on how I can get it in a state where I can do mem->value1 and access the data buffer for raw data bytes?

Comment: Have you read in the manual that `size` needs to be a multiple of a memory page size? Probably a multiple of 4096.

Comment: Also always check the return value of `shmget`, don't assume that it will just work.

Comment: @Cheatah: `size` does not have to be a multiple of the page size; the system will automatically round it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
struct shared_memory_t {
    int value1; 
    int value2;
    char buffer[]; // flexible array member
};

shmid = shmget(key, sizeof(shared_memory_t) + segsize, 0666|IPC_CREAT);
shared_memory_t* mem = (shared_memory_t*) shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
memset(mem.buffer, 42, segsize); // all valid
```

Comment: It really was that simple, after a couple hours reading through the manuals. Thank you!